# What Does STORE_PRIMARYINPUTSUNAVAILABLEBEYONDLIMIT mean?

Tags: u-sql

I recently ran into a strange problem. I ran a script that took all files that we got from 0:00 to 12:00. That one fail with the following error STORE_PRIMARYINPUTSUNAVAILABLEBEYONDLIMIT.

The input to the job is 242 small files.

When I ran the same job from 0:00 to 8:00 it succeeded also the job from 8:00 to 12 succeeded.

This make me a bit confused, is there some limitation in ADLA with the number on incoming files?

Note, that we have now started to merge the files so the error does not occur anymore since the files are much bigger and fewer in quuantity.

Thansk in advance!

Comment: Is this reported as system error or user error?

Answer (score 0):

I think MS has changed something on their end on how files are handled, even for us it failed with same error today, but when I tried again it worked fine. I will contact MS and post more details if I get any.

Comment: Following up on this. Could you connect with MS to check the reason for this error?